# Does this function swapping pattern have a name?

Tags: javascript

I had a function that needs to check 2 conditions before doing something.
This function gets run *a lot* so, even though the first condition is not particularly slow to check (and is the faster of the 2) it still adds up to a not insignificant amount of time.

```
function checkBothConditions() {
  if (condition1){
    if (condition2) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

In my specific case, once condition1 becomes true once, it will remain true at least until condition2 also becomes true.

Thus I realised that I can eliminate the first test for a period of time by replacing the function.

```
let checkBothConditions;
const onlyCheckCondition1 = function() {
  if (condition1) {
    checkBothConditions = onlyCheckCondition2; //skip condition1 check next time
    onlyCheckCondition2(); // run the 2nd test right away
  }
}
const onlyCheckCondition2 = function() {
  if (condition2) {
    // do stuff
    checkBothConditions = onlyCheckCondition1; // reinstate check for condition1. since it may no longer be true.
  }
}
checkBothConditions = onlyCheckCondition1;
```

This code is significantly faster in my specific case (although I wouldn't expect it to be faster in the general case!)

Is there a name for this pattern of swapping functions around for performance reasons?

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for swapping this *for performance reasons*. There are a few names for dynamically altering some function. With that said, I'm not sure why you need to swap. If you make a function `evaluageCondition1` then it can cache the result once it's `true` (since it's not going to change) and repeat calls won't need to re-calculate every time.

Comment: Idk any name pattern of this, though a lot devs do use it. What is preventing you from using flags /w switch ?

Comment: Memoization would be cleaner than function swapping.

Comment: Actually, in my case the first condition is so trivial that even just setting a flag and testing that flag would likely make negligable difference
the condition is literally just `this.#privatefield1 > this.#privateField2.publicField`. I think its the fact that it needs to test anything at all that is the bottle neck here. Crazy, I know, but it really does make a big difference to eliminate it.
There isn't any calculation, only a simple comparison (+ 3 field lookups)